# Backbone bind event to model. Bind if value equal to parameter

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have the following `View`:

```
var PageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: Models.MyModel,

    initialize: function () {
        this.state = window.state;
        this.state.on("change", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function () {
    }
});
```

The `state` is an another `Model` that will contain different global settings like: pageNumber, pageSize and etc.

So my question is: is it possible to change `this.state.on("change", this.render, this);` to something like:

```
this.state.on("change:pageNumber=2", this.render, this);
```

i.e. `this.render` will be executed after `state` is changed and only if `pageNumber` property will be equal to `2`.

I know that I can just place `if` statement into `render` method but if there is way to do that like above it will be greater.


Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone does not offer a filtering mechanism on events, but you could alter your state model to trigger custom events with the signature you wish.

For example, let's say `state` is an instance of this class

```
var EqualBindModel = Backbone.Model.extend({

    arm: function(attribute, watchvalue) {
        this.on('change:'+attribute, function(model, val, options) {
            if (watchvalue === val)
                model.trigger('change:'+attribute+'='+val, model, val, options);
        });
    }

});
```

you could then setup your custom event with

```
var state = new EqualBindModel();
state.arm('pageNumber', 2);
```

and listen to with

```
state.on("change:pageNumber=2", function(model, value, options) {
    console.log('event change:pageNumber=2');
});
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/ZCab8/1/